# On the number of $i$'s in $i$th column of a matrix

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ with entries in the set $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$. Is it possible (only by permuting the columns) to reach from $A$ to a matrix $B = [b_{ij}]$ such that
$$ |\{ (i,j) \; | \; b_{ij} = j \}| \leq n $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we sum the values $|\{(i, j)\mid b_{ij} = j\}|$ over *all possible* permuted matrices $B$, each cell would contribute to that count a total of $(n-1)!$ times. Since there are $n^2$ cells, that means that the total sum is $(n-1)!\cdot n^2 = n!\cdot n$.

But there are $n!$ possible such matrices $B$. So we have a sum of $n!$ terms, adding up to $n!\cdot n$, therefore some of the terms must be less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: Brilliant, kudos.